# Jasper Reports and web services

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper report fetching 500 records of data and displaying it. 
Can we convert this Jasper report to a web service and act as a data feeder to other application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [JasperExportManager.exportReportToXmlFile](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperExportManager.html#exportToXmlFile(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)), this will create a **xml** representation of your report (acting as webservice providing xml to other applications).

Currently no `JSON` exporter is available see [JSON output format via API Tracker](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/3461) but as indicated in tracker you can create your own exporter extending for example the [JRCsvExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRCsvExporter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well..  It can be done. Jasper had discontinued support for SOAP Web services but you can use legacy soap api powered by Jasper if you desperately.  If you are thinking to implement with Restful Web services,  then you are on right track as it is supported by Jasper.

Refer this link: [Jasper Web service](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-rest-web-service-api)